# Google Maps plugin jMapping won't display map, not even with the example code

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to get started using [jMapping](http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/examples/basic.html), but I cannot get a map to display. In fact, even when I paste the exact code from the example page it doesn't work.

Now, as you can see the [example](http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/examples/basic.html) on the jMapping website works, but when I host it, no luck: [The map doesn't display](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/jmapping.html).

Any ideas? I'm quite confused, I've compared the sources and I can't figure out what is happening. Tested in FF4 and Chrome 15.0.874.106.

Comment: have you include the plugin file?

Comment: What does Firebug say? It can't just be that "nothing happens" whatsoever. And if it does then, well, we can't help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.metadata.js isn't loading.

http://www.vitalitypilates.com/js/jquery.metadata.js - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

jquery.jmapping.js:100 - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'metadata'

Comment: Yep that was it. Thank you so much. I knew it would be a stupid mistake.

Comment: "Yes, all the necessary javascript files are hosted in the /js directory, just like the example site" >.<

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Yeah, I was wrong. I made a mistake and could not figure it out. I'm grateful that people on this site are gracious and helpful.

Comment: @AndrewR Glad to help - We all make these mistakes. Next time javascript is giving you trouble, use an inspector like firebug or chrome's inspector to see if there are any errors in the console. It's usually a pretty quick method of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
js/jquery.metadata.js
```

This file is missing.
check the path or may be typo.